# Как работать с селениумом в докере используя прокси?

Tags: python, selenium

**Я пытаюсь запустить этот код в разных вариациях, но всегда получаю свой же ip**

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PROXY = "http://login:password@host:address"

keep_alive = True
browser_profile = None
proxy_object = Proxy(raw={'httpProxy': PROXY, 'sslProxy': PROXY})

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
proxy_object.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
capabilities['class'] = "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy"
capabilities['platform'] = "Linux"
capabilities['version'] = "10"
capabilities["autodetect"] = False

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=capabilities,
                          options=chrome_options
                          )

driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
ip = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ip span'))).text

country = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.value-country a'))).text
print(ip, country)```
````

Comment: Внутри докер контейнера localhost это и есть этот самый контейнер. Куда стучитесь? В другой контейнер? Обращайтесь к нему по имени. На свой хост? Подставьте его IP

Comment: Я подключаюсь к локальному контейнеру в докере по localhost:4444, при этом указываю прокси, что бы через него осуществлялись запросы

Comment: docker-compose используется?